# starting address of the delta plc AS228p-A in Modbus TCP/Ip connection

Tags: labview, plc, modbus-tcp

I try to communicate the delta plc AS228P-A with LabVIEW in the Modbus TCP/ip master, the communication through LabVIEW device is connected but the data are not received from the plc the starting address of plc is the one of the variables to communicate through it. so, I try varies address (0,1,4000,4-10,1024,2046) but it is not communicated yet

I need to read the input of the plc in LabVIEW

Comment: "data are not received" - please let us know what does happen (error etc). You will also need to let us know what Modbus function/registers you are trying to access (this will vary depending upon what is running on the PLC). Ideally use another app (e.g. [one of the tools suggested here](https://www.dalescott.net/modbus-development/)) to confirm that the issue is with your Labview setup and not a PLC/comms problem (and share details of what worked with that tool).